# JSchException Cannot find message

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I want to know some of the reasons that can cause below exception. I am unable to find this message `Cannot find message` in `jsch-0.1.54.jar`. There exists some straight forward messages like `file not found` and others that make sense. But I need more information about this one so that I can reach to the root cause.

```
SftpException while running get ---> 2: Cannot find message [/destination/file.txt]
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1741)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1758)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:786)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:750)
at com.iyi.ftp.SFTP.get(SFTP.java:99)
```

Here is my calling method.

```
public boolean get(final String remoteFile, final String localFile) throws JSchException {
    Vector connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    ChannelSftp c = null;
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        connection = this.connect();
        session = connection.get(0);
        c = connection.get(1);
        c.get(remoteFile, localFile);
        status = true;
    }
    catch (JSchException e) {
        SFTP.LGR.warn((Object)("JSchException in SFTP::get() ---> " + FTPFactory.getStackTrace((Throwable)e)));
        throw e;
    }
    catch (SftpException e2) {
        SFTP.LGR.warn((Object)("SftpException while running get ---> " + FTPFactory.getStackTrace((Throwable)e2)));
        throw new JSchException(e2.getMessage());
    }
    catch (CredentialDecryptionException e3) {
        SFTP.LGR.error((Object)"##CredentialDecryptionException##", (Throwable)e3);
        throw new JSchException(e3.getMessage(), (Throwable)e3);
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.quit();
        }
        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
    if (c != null) {
        c.quit();
    }
    if (session != null) {
        session.disconnect();
    }
    return status;
}
```

These methods are fetched from `jsch-0.1.54.jar` which is an open source utility.

```
public void get(String src, String dst, final SftpProgressMonitor monitor, final int mode) throws SftpException {
    boolean _dstExist = false;
    String _dst = null;
    try {
        ((MyPipedInputStream)this.io_in).updateReadSide();
        src = this.remoteAbsolutePath(src);
        dst = this.localAbsolutePath(dst);
        final Vector v = this.glob_remote(src);
        final int vsize = v.size();
        if (vsize == 0) {
            throw new SftpException(2, "No such file");
        }
        final File dstFile = new File(dst);
        final boolean isDstDir = dstFile.isDirectory();
        StringBuffer dstsb = null;
        if (isDstDir) {
            if (!dst.endsWith(ChannelSftp.file_separator)) {
                dst += ChannelSftp.file_separator;
            }
            dstsb = new StringBuffer(dst);
        }
        else if (vsize > 1) {
            throw new SftpException(4, "Copying multiple files, but destination is missing or a file.");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < vsize; ++j) {
            final String _src = v.elementAt(j);
            final SftpATTRS attr = this._stat(_src);
            if (attr.isDir()) {
                throw new SftpException(4, "not supported to get directory " + _src);
            }
            _dst = null;
            if (isDstDir) {
                final int i = _src.lastIndexOf(47);
                if (i == -1) {
                    dstsb.append(_src);
                }
                else {
                    dstsb.append(_src.substring(i + 1));
                }
                _dst = dstsb.toString();
                if (_dst.indexOf("..") != -1) {
                    final String dstc = new File(dst).getCanonicalPath();
                    final String _dstc = new File(_dst).getCanonicalPath();
                    if (_dstc.length() <= dstc.length() || !_dstc.substring(0, dstc.length() + 1).equals(dstc + ChannelSftp.file_separator)) {
                        throw new SftpException(4, "writing to an unexpected file " + _src);
                    }
                }
                dstsb.delete(dst.length(), _dst.length());
            }
            else {
                _dst = dst;
            }
            final File _dstFile = new File(_dst);
            if (mode == 1) {
                final long size_of_src = attr.getSize();
                final long size_of_dst = _dstFile.length();
                if (size_of_dst > size_of_src) {
                    throw new SftpException(4, "failed to resume for " + _dst);
                }
                if (size_of_dst == size_of_src) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (monitor != null) {
                monitor.init(1, _src, _dst, attr.getSize());
                if (mode == 1) {
                    monitor.count(_dstFile.length());
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            _dstExist = _dstFile.exists();
            try {
                if (mode == 0) {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(_dst);
                }
                else {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(_dst, true);
                }
                this._get(_src, fos, monitor, mode, new File(_dst).length());
            }
            finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (!_dstExist && _dst != null) {
            final File _dstFile2 = new File(_dst);
            if (_dstFile2.exists() && _dstFile2.length() == 0L) {
                _dstFile2.delete();
            }
        }
        if (e instanceof SftpException) {
            throw (SftpException)e;
        }
        if (e instanceof Throwable) {
            throw new SftpException(4, "", e);
        }
        throw new SftpException(4, "");
    }
}

private SftpATTRS _stat(final byte[] path) throws SftpException {
    try {
        this.sendSTAT(path);
        Header header = new Header();
        header = this.header(this.buf, header);
        final int length = header.length;
        final int type = header.type;
        this.fill(this.buf, length);
        if (type != 105) {
            if (type == 101) {
                final int i = this.buf.getInt();
                this.throwStatusError(this.buf, i);
            }
            throw new SftpException(4, "");
        }
        final SftpATTRS attr = SftpATTRS.getATTR(this.buf);
        return attr;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof SftpException) {
            throw (SftpException)e;
        }
        if (e instanceof Throwable) {
            throw new SftpException(4, "", e);
        }
        throw new SftpException(4, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: This get method in particular jar is expecting 4 arguments and you have passed only 2 as argument

Comment: @NitinSinghal Yes, there exists other wrapper methods that pass control to this one and they are not necessary to mention. Furthermore, the issue is not related to number of arguments.

Comment: Did you check connection, session and channelSftp objects have proper values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message comes from your server. It's indeed quite strange message, but I assume that it's some custom SFTP server that deals with some *"messages"* rather than plain *files*.

So the message basically translates to *"Cannot find file"* error of a traditional SFTP server. Even the error code 2 (`SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE`) supports that.

Your path in `remoteFile` is probably wrong.